# How to ignore a font's intrinsic padding in css

Tags: css, fonts, normalization

I have been given two font filesets to work with, one in OTF format and the other in WOFF. Unfortunately, one of them seems to be rendered differently in different operating systems, causing alignment problems in my layout. The following code and captures illustrate the problem:

CSS:

```
div { float:left; padding:0; margin:0 10px; color:#fff; font-size:25px; }
.galano { background-color:#1a2; font-family: 'Galano Grotesque'; }
.coves  { background-color:#21a; font-family: 'Coves'; }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="galano">padding:0</div>
    <div class="coves" >padding:0</div>
</body>
```

Capture from operating system 1:

[image: Page capture]

Capture from operating system 2:

[image]

Please note how the font with green background seems to include a large intrinsic padding that makes the element considerably higher than it needs to be. I would be able to live with that by taking into account that extra space when aligning elements with different fonts, but unfortunately the location of the text within its bounding box is different in different operating systems, so my adjustments would have to be specific to each operating system.

One option I wish to avoid, if possible, is conditional CSS by whichever means, so my question is: can I use any CSS property to ignore a font's intrinsic padding (making the bounding box only high enough to contain the visible glyphs) so that I can then apply my own padding consistently across operating systems?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does that font comes from, how has it been generated? Do you load different formats (WOFF2, WOFF, TTF, SVG, EOT?) in different browsers and OS? If it's an option, tell the font designer there's a huge problem...

Comment: hmmm good question. not sure about the padding, but you might want to play with the letter spacing using `letter-spacing:`

Comment: Thanks @FelipeAls. I don't know where the font came from, I was given it by the designer of a brochure, but I don't think he designed the fonts he used. I have tried using only OTF or only WOFF files in Chrome, FF, IE 11 and Safari for Windows, in Chrome and Safari for Mac, and in android's default browser. The results seem more OS related than browser related.

Comment: Hello @Roysh, thanks for your suggestion. Do you mean line-height?

Comment: no. there's a css command called `letter-spacing`. 
For example, `.coves { letter-spacing: 1px;}` try to modify the amount of pixels and see how it works out

Comment: Yes, but that lets me adjust the horizontal space between adjacent characters. My problem lies in the vertical space between the characters and the edges of the bounding box. Thanks for the advice, though!

Answer (score 0):

Might be more of a browser incosistency than an OS one. Did you normalize the line-height? E.g.

```
div {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  /* Over here! */
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a valuable idea, Bram. Unfortunately, while setting the line height does allow me to define the height of the bounding box, the layout of the text inside the bounding box is still different in different OSs; one draws the text vertically centered within the available area while the other draws it closer to the bottom edge. The results seem not related to the browser but to the OS (I've tried different browsers in one OS, and then two of them in another OS). I suppose I could manually set the line height to the minimum required and then apply my padding. Maintenance nightmare! :-(